# Spark Java edit data in column

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I would like to iterate through the content of a column in a spark `DataFrame` and correct the data within a cell if it meets a certain condition

```
+-------------+
|column_title |
+-------------+
+-----+
|null |
+-----+
+-----+
|0    |
+-----+
+-----+
|1    |
+-----+
```

Lets say I want to display something else when value of column is null, I tried with

`Column.when()`
`DataSet.withColumn()`

But I cant find the right method, i don't think it would be necessary to convert to RDD and iterate through it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `when` and `equalTo` or `when` and `isNull`.

```
Dataset<Row> df1 = df.withColumn("value", when(col("value").equalTo("bbb"), "ccc").otherwise(col("value")));

Dataset<Row> df2 = df.withColumn("value", when(col("value").isNull(), "ccc").otherwise(col("value")));
```

If you only want to replace null values then you can also use `na` and `fill`.

```
Dataset<Row> df3 = df.na().fill("ccc");
```

Comment: Can we do df.withColumn("*",..) if we intend to run the replacement in all the columns?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this could be by using UDF.

Create a UDF:

```
private static UDF1 myUdf = new UDF1<String, String>() {
public String call(final String str) throws Exception {
    // any condition or custom function can be used
    return StringUtils.rightPad(str, 25, 'A');
  }
};
```

Register UDF in SparkSession:

```
sparkSession.udf().register("myUdf", myUdf, DataTypes.StringType);
```

Apply udf on dataset:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = dataset.withColumn("city", functions.callUDF("myudf", col("city")));
```

Comment: Edits that remove fluff [are fine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/6296561). Please refrain from further rollbacks.